# clearer explanation of function level scope for recursion

Tags: matlab, recursion, scope

This is an example from the book 'Matlab for Neuroscientists'.  I don't understand the order in which, or why, g gets assigned a new value after each recursion.  Nor do I understand why "factorial2" is included in the final line of code.

here is a link to the text

[image]

Basically, I am asking for someone to re-word the authors explanation (circled in red) of how the function works, as if they were explaining the concept and processes to a 5-year old.  I'm brand new to programming.  I thought I understood how this worked from reading another book, but now this authors explanation is causing nothing but confusion.  Many thanks to anyone who can help!!

Comment: oh wow, this is pretty helpful.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_-C7ILgFQo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive method works by breaking a larger problem into smaller problems **each time the method is called.** This allows you to break what would be a difficult problem; a factorial summation, into a series of smaller problems.

Each recursive function has 2 parts:
1) **The base case**: The lowest value that we care about evaluating. Usually this goes to zero or one.

```
if (num == 1)
  out = 1;
end
```

2) **The general case**: The general case is what we are going to call until we reach the base case. We call the function again, but this time with 1 less than the previous function started with. This allows us to work our way towards the base case.

```
out = num + factorial(num-1);
```

This statement means that we are going to **firstly** call the function with 1 less than what **this** function with; we started with three, the next call starts with two, the call after that starts with 1 (Which triggers our base case!)

Once our base case is reached, the methods *"recurse-out"*. This means they bounce backwards, back into the function that called it, bringing all the data from the functions below it!
**It is at this point that our summation actually occurs.**

Once the original function is reached, we have our final summation.

For example, let's say you want the summation of the first 3 integers.
The first recursive call is passed the number 3.

```
  function [out] = factorial(num)
     %//Base case
     if (num == 1)
        out = 1;
     end
  %//General case
  out = num + factorial(num-1);
```

Walking through the function calls:

```
factorial(3); //Initial function call

//Becomes..
factorial(1) + factorial(2) + factorial(3) = returned value
```

This gives us a result of 6!

Comment: I've taken the liberty in editing your post from Java syntax to its equivalent MATLAB syntax as the question is asking in terms of MATLAB.  Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thank you! I am not familiar with MATLAB, but did my best to explain it clearly in what I knew :)

Comment: You did explain recursion quite well, and it's certainly one of those concepts that flat out sucks when you try to learn it the first time.  I figured it would be more inclined to be accepted if it was in code that the OP could understand.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks to both you! The explanation is thorough and clear, Evan.  And thanks for changing the code to MATLAB syntax rayryeng!