# How to get fibonacci sequence using recursion?

Tags: matlab, recursion, fibonacci

I am trying to find the fib sequence using recursion but my function keeps giving me an error.

```
function y = r_nFib(seq, n)
y = zeros(1,n);
for m = 1:n
    y(m) = r_nFib(m);
end
if seq == 0
    y = [0 y];
else
    y = [seq, seq, y];
function y = r_nFib(seq, n)
if n<3
   y(1:n) = 1;
else
    y(n) = r_nFib(n-2) + r_nFib(n-1);
end
    y = y(n);
end
end
```

n is the length of the fib sequence and seq is the starting number. If seq is 0 then this is how the sequence is going to start

```
y = [0 1 1 2 3 5 8] % first two number will be the 0 and 1
```

if seq is any thing other than 0, then

if seq = 2;

```
y = [2 2 4 6 10] % first two number will be the seq
```

How do I correct my function to give me the right answer. I have never used recursion and I am new to it. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
y = r_nFib(4,10)
y = [4 4 8 12 20 32 52 84 136 220];
```

Thank you.

Comment: Don't put local functions inside the main function; put it after the `end` of the main function. It still works and won't be visible to outside callers.

Comment: I still get an error saying Error using r_nFib (line 2)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in r_nFib (line 4)
    y(m) = r_nFib(m);

Comment: By the way, to be pedantic the Fibonacci Sequence is _defined_ to have a starting pair of either `[0 1]` or `[1 1]`; any other starting pairs are Fibonacci-like but not strictly Fibonacci. The distinction is important because they have different properties (see [Lucas Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number))

Comment: You get that because your function requires 2 input parameters but you only passed 1. If you want the second to be optional you need to explicitly implement that. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764062/optional-arguments-in-matlab-functions)

Comment: Also, [nested functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html#btfml3d) cannot be defined within `if` statements. Additionally, you can't define a nested or local function with the same name as the main function, so the second `r_nFib` needs a different name; although I don't think you need a second function once the control flow is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function y = r_nFib(seq, n)

if length(seq) == 1
    if seq == 0
        seq = [0, 1];
    else
        seq = [seq, seq];
    end
end

if length(seq) >= n
    y = seq;
else
    y = r_nFib([seq (seq(end - 1) + seq(end))], n);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that I typed up for matlab, explaining recursion:

---

A recursive method works by breaking a larger problem into smaller problems **each time the method is called.** This allows you to break what would be a difficult problem; a factorial summation, into a series of smaller problems.

Each recursive function has 2 parts:
1) **The base case**: The lowest value that we care about evaluating. Usually this goes to zero or one.

```
if (num == 1)
  out = 1;
end
```

2) **The general case**: The general case is what we are going to call until we reach the base case. We call the function again, but this time with 1 less than the previous function started with. This allows us to work our way towards the base case.

```
out = num + factorial(num-1);
```

This statement means that we are going to **firstly** call the function with 1 less than what **this** function with; we started with three, the next call starts with two, the call after that starts with 1 (Which triggers our base case!)

Once our base case is reached, the methods *"recurse-out"*. This means they bounce backwards, back into the function that called it, bringing all the data from the functions below it!
**It is at this point that our summation actually occurs.**

Once the original function is reached, we have our final summation.

For example, let's say you want the summation of the first 3 integers.
The first recursive call is passed the number 3.

```
  function [out] = factorial(num)
     %//Base case
     if (num == 1)
        out = 1;
     end
  %//General case
  out = num + factorial(num-1);
```

Walking through the function calls:

```
factorial(3); //Initial function call

//Becomes..
factorial(1) + factorial(2) + factorial(3) = returned value
```

This gives us a result of 6!

---

[matlab - Clearer explanation of recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28290092/4515720)